# Postgresql: efficiency of separate UPSERTs (INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT) vs combining into single command

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, upsert

Which of the following multiple `UPSERT` operations is more *efficient* (equating to faster to perform)?  Or does it not make any difference?

Separate queries:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col_1, col_2) VALUES (312, 42) ON CONFLICT col_1 DO UPDATE SET col_2=excluded.col_2;
INSERT INTO mytable (col_1, col_2) VALUES (933, 32) ON CONFLICT col_1 DO UPDATE SET col_2=excluded.col_2;
...
INSERT INTO mytable (col_1, col_2) VALUES (121, 16) ON CONFLICT col_1 DO UPDATE SET col_2=excluded.col_2;
```

Or the same commands combined into a single query:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col_1, col_2) VALUES
    (312, 42) ON CONFLICT col_1 DO UPDATE SET col_2=excluded.col_2
    (933, 32) ON CONFLICT col_1 DO UPDATE SET col_2=excluded.col_2
    ...
    (121, 16) ON CONFLICT col_1 DO UPDATE SET col_2=excluded.col_2;
```

Bear in mind that I am talking about a **lot** of `INSERT` commands to be done... in multiple batches (lots of them) each of roughly 750000 `INSERT` commands.

Comment: you can only have a **single** `on conflict` clause. And yes, usually a single insert is more efficient than many single-row inserts

Comment: Oh dang, I need to do multiple UPSERT operations... no way other than as separate inserts, thereby being less-than-efficient?  Takes forever to do so many inserts and am looking at ways of improving it.

Comment: you seem to update the same column in each INSERT statement.

Comment: ? I am inserting multiple rows into the same table, where `col_1` is the `PRIMARY KEY` for the table and `col_2` holds a meaningful value... there are lots of different values associated with different respective keys... isn't that kinda normal for a table in a database?

Comment: `excluded.col_2` references the corresponding value from the row that caused the conflict.

Comment: not sure I follow.  Taking the last line, this is saying that if `121` already exists in `col_1` (conflict) then update `col_2` to have the value of `16` instead of whatever it is now.  I can't see any issue with that?  Other than using conflict statements on every line which I now know is the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @a_horse_with_no_name said in the comments, running a single statement is usually more efficient than multiple ones. However, the proper syntax for that is

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col_1, col_2)
VALUES
    (312, 42),
    (933, 32),
    ...
    (121, 16)
ON CONFLICT col_1 DO UPDATE
    SET col_2 = excluded.col_2;
```

Notice that when you do this with a parameterised query, there's a limit to the number of parameters so you might have to batch them.

Comment: Some follow-ups: "usually"... why only "usually"?  Does there come a point (e.g. some time before combining all 750000 of these into a single statement) where it becomes *less* efficient?  And are we talking about "marginally better" or "wow so much better"?  And regarding the `ON CONFLICT`... does that work for a conflict with **any** of the inserts?

Comment: Usually, because I don't want to rule out some edge case. For N=1 they're by definition the same :-) There might be cases for large (non-integer) values where the difference is smaller because most time is spent on serialising/transmitting/deserialising the values. There might be cases where the client becomes less efficient because it cannot deal with large strings in memory. Yes, the differences could be large, the only way to make sure is to benchmark. Try one large query vs many ad-hoc queries vs many queries with a prepared statement.

Comment: Regarding `ON CONFLICT`, yes that works for any inserted row. It is semantically part of the `INSERT` statement, not of the `VALUES` expression. However, as pointed out by @ИгорьТыра in his answer, you need to ensure that there are no duplicates (i.e. no two input values conflicting with the same existing row)

Comment: It is indeed significantly faster.  I haven't done a proper benchmark but there is no doubt that it is much faster by a long stretch.  So far I'm batching that ~750000 updates into 1000 lots of 750.  Next I might try running the full 750000 as a single batch and see how it copes.

Answer (score 2):

in your case the first variant is only safe.

while using `ON CONFLICT` clause it is unsafe to insert multiple records in single query, you can get the fatal error like `"ON CONFLICT can not affect the same row twice."` if two of inserted rows have the same value of conflict key.

Comment: I think it's usually safe to assume that there are no duplicate ids in the input values, the normal concern is only that the input conflicts with the existing data in the table.

Comment: i think you can be sure about input data uniqueness only if you generate this data by yourself

Comment: But avoiding "on conflict" is no safer given the scenario of duplicate keys on input. The only difference being the error is "duplicate key value violates unique constraint". Viewed transitionally there is no difference.

Comment: not avoiding single "on conflict" (simply resolved by DO UPDATE), but avoiding "on multi-conflict" (which is fatal)